# Series of novels about a future Britain with a lot of musicians as part of the government?

Tags: story-identification, history, rock-music

These are rock-ish musicians who go around giving a lot of concerts (described in detail) that either pacify or rouse up the audience. They also engage in street fighting, and are part of a group that has staged a coup? I can't remember the author or any of the titles, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 5):

That's the "Rock and Roll Reich" aka "Bold as Love" series by Gwyneth Jones. The first book is *[Bold as Love](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bold_as_Love_(novel))*, and there are six books so far (the sixth one being self-published).

To quote Wikipedia:

> Ax Preston, a mixed-race guitarist from Taunton, having survived a
>   government-organised massacre of the official Green Party (under cover
>   of a pop-culture reception à la "Cool Britannia" in Hyde Park),
>   emerges from the ensuing chaos as the true leader England desperately
>   needs. He and his friends, also Indie musicians, tackle an outrageous
>   series of disasters, including a minor war with Islamic Separatists in
>   Yorkshire, and a hippie President who turns out to be a murdering
>   paedophile.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's it!

Comment: @user72923 Perhaps you could accept this answer, then.